# Arduino and rosserial: reliable for industrial applications?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to run a ServiceServer on an Arduino board, but Googling around I'm not seeing a lot of success stories, just lots of posts about problems, with no solution. For example: [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/77681/serviceserver-on-arduino-service-requests-will-eventually-hang/) kind of thing.

This is for an industrial application, and we're looking for high-reliability.
Questions:

- Should I forget about Arduino and just go straight to C/C++?
- Anyone here have good experiences with Arduino and rosserial's ServiceServer?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262076/arduino-and-rosserial:-reliable-for-industrial-applications?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2017-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My advice would be to change your application to use topics instead of services.

The paradigm is not the same but it is the fact that a service is blocking that make it less reliable with a serial link.

Rosserial with only topics seems reliable enough because it is already used by several companies.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-10-01**:
That's exactly what I ended up doing (using topics instead of services). Thanks.